# Input type number with comma React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, input

I have a question about input type number in React.
I need to display dot separator if user enter number with comma.
Like this

```
11,2
```

Should convert to

```
11.2
```

How I can convert this number?I try

```
value.replace(/,/g, '.')
```

But this isn't working.I still see comma in my input.

PS:
This how I handle input

```
<input
type="number"
placeholder='Input'
name="inputValue"
step="0.01"
inputMode="decimal"
id='inputValue'
min="0"
value={inputValue}
onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

And this is my handleChange function

```
const handleChange = e => {
let { name, value } = e.target;
value = value.replace(/,/g, '.');
setData(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value}));
    }
```

Comment: Can you share you whole code with input box and the function where you are changing ,(comma) to .(dot)?

Comment: How are you setting state?

Comment: Is comma allowed in `type="number"`?

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya Hi, I add my input code to question body

Comment: @Andy Hi, I add code to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
const Number = "11,1";

console.log(Number.replace(/\,/, "."));
```

```js
//Now your handleChange function will look like this:

const handleChange = e => {
  let { name, value } = e.target;
  value = value.replace(/\,/, ".");
  setData(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value}));
}
```